# Show proportion with multiple conditions in R

Tags: r

I have:

```
> dataframe
 GENDER CITY  NUMBER
 Male   NY    1
 Female Paris 2
 Male   Paris 1
 Female NY    
 Female NY    2
 Male   Paris 2
 Male   Paris  
 Male   Paris 1
 Female NY    2
 Female Paris 1
```

And I would like to return the proportion of Male and Female in bomb city (then in NY) who has 2 as a third column (The DF is way longer that my example), knowing that there are empty rows in NUMBER column.
Technically speaking I want to show a proportion with two conditions (and more conditions in the future).
I tried:

```
prop.table(table(dataframe$GENDER, dataframe$CITY == 'NY' & dataframe$NUMBER == 2)
```

But this gives me the wrong results.
The xxpected output (or any that is close to this):

```
          NY      
Male      0        
Female    20
```

Do you have any idea how I can get this?
The best would be to have a column per city

Comment: add `useNA = 'ifany'` to your `table` call

Comment: Please add `dput(dataframe)` to facilitate answering your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the environment data.table, that makes your life much more easier. It uses SQL syntax and its superfast in case your data grows up. The code should be:

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(yourdataframe)

df[, summary(GENDER), by = CITY]
```

The output should give you the count of each value

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work either since I have to conditions to meet. 1st one is that the city is NY and the second is that NUMBER == 2. There is a problem when conditionning numbers with logicals (count + true/false)

Comment: If you have two conditions, use `by = list(CITY, NUMBER)`. Indeed, you can input as many conditions as you need.